# What is the probability that the engines will allow a safe landing?

Tags: probability

Each of the four engines of an airplane are functioning corectly on
a given flight with probability of 0.99, and the engines function independently of
each other. Assume that the plane can make a safe landing if at least two of its
engines are functioning properly. What is the probability that the engines will
allow a safe landing?

#### Progress

I tried to calculate sum of probabilities when all 4 work + (3 work and 1 doesn't) + and so on till all 4 don't work.
Also Bernoulli trials $b(n,p,j)$ with the same idea. I know the result $(0.99999603)$ but can't get to it.

Comment: I tried to calculate sum of probabilities when all 4 works+3 works and 1 doesn't + and so on till all 4 don't work. Also Bernoulli trials b(n,p,j) with the same idea. I know the result(0.99999603)but can't get to it.

Answer (score 2):

The probability that the engines will allow a safe landing is equal to $1$ minus the probability that at least three engines will fail.

The probability that four engines fail is

$$\binom{4}{4}(0.01)^4$$

where $\binom{4}{4}$ represents the number of ways all four engines can fail and $0.01 = 1 - 0.99$ is the probability that a given engine fails.

The probability that three engines fail is

$$\binom{4}{3}(0.01)^3(0.99)$$

where $\binom{4}{3}$ is the number of ways three of the four engines can fail, $0.01$ represents the probability that a given engine fails, and $0.99$ represents the probability that the fourth engine works.

Hence, the probability that the engines will allow a safe landing is

$$1 - \left[\binom{4}{4}(0.01)^4 + \binom{4}{3}(0.01)^3(0.99)\right] \approx 0.99999603$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I forgot about some important coditions of the exercise when I tried to sole it by myself.